# Xamarin.iOS SQLiteException: Corrupt

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm building an application with Xamarin.Forms and a Portable Class Library.The app can be used on Android, iOS and UWP. 
I've been building a database which now works on both Android and UWP. When I use the same code and run it on iOS it gives me some errors.

This is the exception message:

> Unhandled Exception: SQLite.SQLiteException: Corrupt

This is the StackTrace:

```
  at SQLite.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery (System.Object[] source) [0x00116] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2480 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj, System.String extra, System.Type objType) [0x0010e] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:1381 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at App2.Model.Database.FormDAO+<InsertItem>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00066] in D:\SourceTree\App2\App2\Model\Database\FormDAO.cs:25
```

This is the code where the unhandled exception is:

```
public async void InsertItem(Form Form)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Insert(Form)); //this line 
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e.message" + e.Message + ";;;;" + e.StackTrace);
     }
}
```

The function InsertItem(form) is called about 1000 times from another async method.

Why does this code not work on iOS?

Edit: 
Other error I get is:

> SQLite.SQLiteException: IOError

StackTrace:

```
  at SQLite.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery (System.Object[] source) [0x00116] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2480 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj, System.String extra, System.Type objType) [0x0010e] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:1381 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/ad1cd42d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at App2.Model.Database.CourseDAO+<InsertItem>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00055] in D:\SourceTree\App2\App2\Model\Database\CourseDAO.cs:26
```

This exception is throwed when using almost the same method but then with this line:

```
 var result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Insert(Course));
```

Comment: `The database disk image is malformed` : Try manually deleting the app from the device/simulator to delete the database and retry. You might want to look at serializing your db operations through a queue vs. preforming these inserts on different tasks/threads.

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you have a example of serializing db operations through a queue ?

Comment: Use ConcurrentQueue to add your "Course". Create a Task trying to get objects from queue and insert to DB. This task will serialise writes to DB. Make writes to queue async but don't make write to DB async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the async calls to the database as **Yuri S** and **SushiHangover** pointed out in the comments.

First I didn't thought that the problem were the async calls to the database because it did work on Android and UWP. But when I made all the calls synchronised the database did work on all the three platforms: UWP, Android, iOS.

Thanks!